# How to update over 100K items in MongoDB efficiently when new value is a calculation result from another collection using

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a large list (100K+) where have to update all products by getting values from another collection. Basically I have to get the lowest offer and the number of offers for each product.
I am using C# driver and using a for loop it is easily achievable to do this, but when you have over 100K products and within each loop you need to do two calls to the `productOffers` collection (1: get lowest offer, 2: get count of offers), it becomes unacceptably slow.

There must be a better way of doing this. I read about `JS procedures`, but seems like everyone advice against it and not sure if you can run something like this within a `JS procedures`. I have also thought about running the loop parallel, but that sounds unstable and probably will run into network or other type of errors.

Product example:

```
{
 "_id": "..",
 "minPrice: "40",
 "numberOfOffers": "2"
}
```

Product offer example:

```
{
  "_id": "..",
  "productId": ".."
  "price: "40"
}
```

Comment: Consider reading in all the documents via your app (into your app memory space) in one query.  Calculate the updates you need and provide them as a bulk write option to MongoDB.  Create batches of around 100,000 documents per bulkwrite operation.  100,000 is the limit with MongoDB - see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from mongo v4.2 you can merge results of aggregation pipeline into documents in other collection https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/

The aggregation query on productOffers to calculate minPrice and count per product id and update products with results:

```
db.productOffers.aggregate([
    { $group: {
        _id: "$productId", 
        minPrice: {$min: "$price"}, 
        numberOfOffers: {$sum: 1}
    } },
    { $merge : { into : "products" } }
])
```

Think about what you gonna do with product offers that has no matching product id and add whenNotMatched option to the $merge stage to insert or ignore the document or fail the query.

The whole thing will run on mongodb side so you will not transfer data to and from the app.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Alex. I just need to translate it to the C# driver